# Regex getting brackets PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string `"<?php jifoafj sfjifasjfoasjfifajs ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)) oisfjoijsiofsa sffas ?>"`

I am trying to get whatever's inside ReadThis.

This is the Regex so far,

`preg_match_all('~<\?(?:php)?\s+ReadThis\(([^)]+)\).*?\?>~s',$thestring,$matches) ;`

Ok, but I am getting

`array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35`

what I want is

`array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)`

What is the best approach to accomplishing this? Does this have something todo with the Chomsky Hierarchy?

Comment: What is a chrome hierarchy?

Comment: I was looking for the answer online, and I ran into something called the Chomsky Hierarchy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

Comment: Do you know in advance how many pairs of brackets will be inside of `ReadThis()`? If you do, you can solve this with a regex. If it can be arbitrarily many, you cannot solve this with a regex.

Comment: @Patashu Yes you can, but it would require a recursive regex, which is quite complex.

Comment: Really?? Wow, I cant solve this with any simple method? I don't know how many bracket pairs will be inside of ReadThis.

Comment: @A A The reason is that regexes are not designed to count. Think about what it would need to do, it would need to count 1 for every opening bracket, count -1 for every closing bracket and stop the capture when it reaches 0 again. How would you make that into a regex?

Comment: Hmmmm, It looks like we will have to modify the regex library.

Comment: @AA: it isn't so difficult or complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

This regex will search your sample string and find the ReadThis and the contents of the outer most set of parans.

`<[?](?:php\b)?.*?\s\bReadThis[(]([^)]+[)][^)]*)[)].*?[?]>`

[image]

Group 0 will receive the entire string, and Group 1 will have the readthis through the last paran.

I modified your search:

- by placing the special characters inside square brackets
- added `\b` after `php` and before `readthis` to ensure you don't accidentally find a `readthis` as part of a larger string
- after the first close paran, I've added a second match for 0 or more non parans incase you have additional values inside that you wanted to capture.
- added a second match for the close paran to ensure that it really there

## PHP Example

```
<?php
$sourcestring="<?php jifoafj sfjifasjfoasjfifajs ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)) oisfjoijsiofsa sffas ?>";
preg_match_all('/<[?](?:php\b)?.*?\s\bReadThis[(]([^)]+[)][^)]*)[)].*?[?]>/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <?php jifoafj sfjifasjfoasjfifajs ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)) oisfjoijsiofsa sffas ?>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to match the entire string.

```
(ReadThis\((array\([^)]+\))\))
```

The important thing is to capture that closing parens.

Comment: It will only match this specific string however if input is: `<?php  ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35), 'foo' ); ` then it might not.

Answer (score 1):

This regex doesn't match anything on this string.

Anyway, to fix your issue juste replace **[^)]** by a dot like :

```
~<\?(?:php)?\s+ReadThis\((.+)\).*?\?>~s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
ReadThis(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))+\))
```

Example:

```
$pattern = '~ReadThis(\((?<result>(?:[^()]++|(?1))+)\))~';
$subject = <<<'LOD'
< ?php jifoafj sfjifasjfoasjfifajs ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)) oisfjoijsiofsa sffas  sdfsdf sd
ReadThis(array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35), 'foo') ? >
LOD;
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches['result']);
```

you obtain:

```
array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)
array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35), 'foo'
```

Comment: +1 for use of recursive patterns here. This is the only way as far as I knw. You might want to make it: `ReadThis\s*(\((?<result>(?:[^()]++|(?1))+)\))` though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your pattern correctly matches the full string, but has the ending paren consumed outside of your capture group... Just move the escape sequence for that paren inside of the capture group instead:

```
<\?(?:php)?\s+ReadThis\(([^)]+\)).*?\?>
```

---

(where your original regex reads this; note the moved backslash)

```
<\?(?:php)?\s+ReadThis\(([^)]+)\).*?\?>
```